# Prove with math induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Prove that for each natural number $n$, with $n \geq 3$: $(1+(1/n)^n < n$.

I did the base step, (4/3)^3 < 3 so it holds, but I am confused about the inductive step.

The inductive hypothesis is (1+(1/k)^k < k, and the inductive conclusion is (1+(1/(k+1)))^k+1 < k+1. I can't figure out how to reach the IC from the IH.

I tried multiplying both sides by (1+(1/k), but that just gives (1+(1/k))^k+1 < k+1. Idk what I am supposed to do here?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I used MathJax to properly typeset your first formula.  Please edit your question to do this for the rest of your Post as well, because as it is, it is very hard to read. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please make your titles informative; "prove with math induction" is generic; make it more specific so that people know what to expect going in.

Comment: Notice that $1< (1+ \frac 1{k+1})^{k+1}  < (1+\frac 1k)^{k+1} < k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that $1/(k+1) \leq 1/k$ we have that $$(1+\frac 1{k+1})^{k+1}<(1+1/k)^{k+1}=(1+1/k)(1+1/k)^k \leq (1+1/k)k=k+1$$
And we are done.